# Using a six wire stepper motor with L298n

Tags: stepper-motor

I am using a L298n IC and (not a driver shield) and an Arduino.

I would like to know how to use the IC with the Arduino to run a six wire stepper motor.

Could I have a detailed explanation for wiring the IC connections on the breadboard and the Arduino?

Comment: Have you considered using a more modern [stepper motor driver](http://reprap.org/wiki/stepper_motor_driver)?

Comment: What in particular do you not understand when you read ["Stepper Motor control with L298 & Arduino"](https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/stepper-motor-control-with-l298-arduino/); ["Arduino LM298 and ... stepper motor with 6 wires"](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=66952.0); ["Control of Stepping Motors"](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/step/); ["Arduino L298 stepper motor driver"](http://effluviaofascatteredmind.blogspot.com/2009/03/arduino-l298-stepper-motor-driver.html); etc.?

Comment: I have a l298n IC and I placed it on the breadbord .I would like to know how to make the connections between I.C and arduino.

Comment: I saw some content online but its witg the motor drive shield

Comment: Have you tried reading the [datasheet for the L298](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/l298-954744.pdf)? Have you looked at the [schematic drawing](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_XQ0vbXkszcw/SdVceUCy49I/AAAAAAAAANU/dsFHH2hmaCI/s1600-h/arduino+L298+schematic.jpg) on the [Arduino L298 stepper motor driver](http://effluviaofascatteredmind.blogspot.com/2009/03/arduino-l298-stepper-motor-driver.html) page?

Comment: i havent been much into electronics  .The schematics that i read dont match the I.C that i am using .

There are apparently 14 pins to connect to.I am using this I.C ( http://s3.amazonaws.com/emimg/Products/NN-188/1B.JPG )

Comment: Id like to know the connections to make from IC to Arduino.
Apparently the pins are shown in this image.

(http://www.goodluckbuy.com/images/detailed_images2/image/stepper.gif )

Answer (score 1):

G. Andrew Stone [posted the following schematic of L298N and Arduino with Arduino sketch source code to drive a stepper motor using the L298 chip](http://effluviaofascatteredmind.blogspot.com/2009/03/arduino-l298-stepper-motor-driver.html):

[image: schematic drawing of L298 and Arduino]

```
Pin number on L298N
    pin on Arduino
        function
1   -   SenseA; connect through 0.5 Ohm sense resistor to power GND
2   -   one end of coilA on stepper motor
3   -   other end of coilA on stepper motor
4   -   VS: connect to "42V" motor power, and to the middle wire of both coils.
5   5   IN1
6   "5V"    ENA
7   4       IN2
8   GND     GND (hook to both power supply GND and Arduino GND)
9   "5V"    VSS
10  3       IN2
11  "5V"    ENB
12  2       IN4
13  -   one end of coilB on stepper motor
14  -   other end of coilB on stepper motor
15  -   SenseB; connect through 0.5 Ohm sense resistor to power GND
```

Also:

- connect a capacitor (typically 0.1 uF or 1 uF) between L298 "VS" (4) and GND (8)
- connect a capacitor (typically 0.1 uF or 1 uF) between L298 "Vss" (9) and GND (8)
- connect the motor power supply (42VDC to 5VDC) between L298 "VS" (4) and GND (8)
- external flyback protection diodes
- The L298P -- the same chip in a PowerSO20 package -- has completely different pin numbers. For more details, see the [datasheet for the L298](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/l298-954744.pdf).

Comment: Where is the option to post a photo.Id like to explain with a picture so its a lot easier to understand my question.

Comment: Normally you can hit the "edit" button under your question, click inside the textbox, and hit "Ctrl+g" (The icon above the textbox has changed since ["How to upload an image to a post?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) was written.). It looks like you've recently gained enough reputation to do that -- ["Why can't users with less than 10 reputation points add images while asking question?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268469/why-cant-users-with-less-than-10-reputation-points-add-images-while-asking-ques) .

Answer (score -1):

This is a good tutorial to get you started.

https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2014/04/25/stepper-motor-control-with-l298-arduino/

Comment: As it stands, this is a link only answer. Could you provide a summary, and the relevant information from the article?

Comment: Thanks for your answer but we prefer answers to be self contained where possible. Links [tend to rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot) so answers which rely on a link can be rendered useless if the linked to content disappears. If you add more context from the link, it is more likely that people will find your answer useful.